# How do I get the current x and y position so that I can use GCRectMake?

Tags: ios, swift, cgrectmake

I have this code inside an animation:

```
image.frame = CGRectMake(x: x, y: y, width, height)
```

I need to get the x and y coordinates of an image. I found this Objective-C code:

```
CGPoint origin = imageView.frame.origin;
```

Once I find the x and y position of the image, I will need to transform it. I will use something like:

```
image.frame = CGRectMake(x-50, y-50, width+500, height+500)
```

...so that I can move the image around the screen. How do I find the original x and y positions?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Do you mean you want this?

```
var frm: CGRect = imageView.frame
frm.origin.x = frm.origin.x - 50
frm.origin.y = frm.origin.y - 50
frm.size.width = frm.size.width + 500
frm.size.height = frm.size.height + 500
imageView.frame = frm
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the width and the height original values? Thanks

Comment: `frm.size.width` and `frm.size.height` are original values

Comment: what is frame.origin.y, is it midY, maxY, or minY?